# finding the coefficients of polynomial when reformed

Tags: polynomials

If I reform the following equation

$P = C_n(x-a)^n+C_{n-1}(x-a)^{n-1}+...+C_{1}(x-a)+C_0$

such that:

$P = D_n(x)^n+D_{n-1}(x)^{n-1}+...+D_{1}(x)+D_0$

How do I find the relationship between $D_i$ and $C_i$?

Update:

I have found out that:

$D_n = C_n$

$D_0 = C_0 - aC_1 + a^2C_2 - ... +(-a)^n C_n = \sum_{i=0}^n (-a)^iC_i$

Comment: Do you know the binomial theorem? It tells you the exact coefficients of $(x-a)^k$, for example.

Comment: @GregMartin This helps, I am working on it now. Tnx!